# GCC not found in %PATH%

Tags: gcc, go

I am trying to run this code:

```
package main

import ("github.com/faiface/pixel"
        "github.com/faiface/pixel/pixelgl")

func run(){
    cfg := pixelgl.WindowConfig{
        Title:"My First program",
        Bounds:pixelgl.R(0,0,800,600)
    }
    window,err := pixelgl.NewWindow(cfg)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    for !window.Closed(){
        win.Update()
    }
}       


func main(){
    pixelgl.Run(run)
}
```

but whenever I type

```
go run pixel.go
```

I get this error

```
exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

I have C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin in both my user path and the system path and the system finds gcc easily whenever I type "gcc" into cmd. I have an x64 Windows 10 System

Comment: Have you tried running a simple Go "hello world" on your system to make sure there's no problem with your Go setup/installation?
https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

Comment: It's also recommended to `build` instead of `run` for any non-trivial program; you could try build and then execute and confirm that you get the same error, and tell us whether the error occurs when you build or when you execute.
`go build pixel.go`

Comment: Have you tried to run gcc manually in the same console as go?

Answer (score 1):

You're depending on cgo packages, so you'll need GCC.  I can't find a version of TDM-GCC that's been updated since 2015.  I suggest looking for an alternative MinGW-w64 installation that has been updated more recently, such as this one which I have recently used for OpenGL with Go (1.9.1) on Windows 10 x64:

http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php

You'll need to add the installed directory /bin to your path, as you did for TDM-GCC-64.  You can test by trying `g++` in PowerShell (or cmd) to see whether it's a known command.  You should be able to `go get` packages you need from PowerShell.

If you're still having trouble, make sure you have a relatively recent version of Go installed.

Also, it's always recommended to use `go build` and then run the executable it creates instead of `go run` for any non-trivial code.  If you haven't run any other Go code yet, you could also try [a hello world](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) to make sure there aren't any problems with your Go installation and setup.

[The GLFW installation docs](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile_guide.html#compile_generate) talk about generating build files with cmake, but I don't think you'll need to do that.